# Property "bounds" not found in type view controller

Tags: objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller

i write a code for contain a text into a view as

```
-(void)buildFrames
{
    NSTextStorage *textstorege=[[NSTextStorage alloc]initWithAttributedString:self.bookMarkup];
    _layoutManager =[[NSLayoutManager alloc]init];
    [textstorege addLayoutManager:_layoutManager];
    NSTextContainer *textcontainer=[[NSTextContainer alloc]initWithSize:CGSizeMake(self.bounds.size.width, FLT_MAX)];
    [_layoutManager addTextContainer:textcontainer];
    UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:self.bounds textContainer:textcontainer];
    textView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    [self addSubview:textView];
}
```

then error is like as Property "Bounds" not found in object type view controller...

Comment: Copy the actual error and add it to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line:

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:self.bounds textContainer:textcontainer];
```

If `self` is a `UIViewController` or `UISplitViewController` then `self` doesn't have bounds it's a *controller*. You want the *bounds* of the *view* the controller is responsible for.

Try `self.view.bounds` so your line becomes:

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds textContainer:textcontainer];
```